# Can I tell Entity Framework which constructor to use during add-migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got this really strange exception when running `add-migration`

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name xxx
```

It turns out that the problem was the constructor in the `DbContext` class. It has some options passed to it that it uses during regular runtime, but which made Entity Framework fail. If a deleted the code in the constructor `add-migration` went smooth sailing.

So my question is: can I tell Entity Framework which constructor to use during `add-migration`?

Edit:

Here are how the constructors look. This doesn't work

```
    public MyContext()
    {
        /*EF needs me*/
    }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        if (_isInitted) return;
        if (!ShouldInitInEnvironment(options)) return;
        Database.Migrate();
        PopulateDbWith(new DemoData());
        _isInitted = true;
    }
```

This works:

```
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Do u have a default contructor? If not, thats the issue

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work. I added information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Implement the [`IDbContextFactory<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506876(v=vs.113).aspx) interface in the same project as your `DbContext`:

```
public class YourDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext Create()
    {
        return new MyContext(...);
    }
```

The `Create()` method is called by EF, and you can set up your constructor however you like.